# When to declare function with 'scope' vs. 'var' in directive?

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gu6k5jG9o5ns4NCQyuzU?p=preview) I have a directive that is instantiated twice. In each case, the result of the directive (as defined by its template) is displayed correctly.

Question is whether `getValue2()` needs to be defined as `scope.getValue2` or `var getValue2`. When to use each in the directive?

HTML

```
    instance 1 = <div dirx varx="1"></div>
    <br/>
    instance 2 = <div dirx varx="2"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('dirx', function () {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.scope = {    
            varx: '='
    };

    directive.template = '{{getValue()}}';

    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.getValue = function(){
          return getValue2();
        };

      var getValue2 = function() {
        return scope.varx * 3;
      }

    };

    return directive;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time you need declare something as a property on the `$scope` object is when it is part of your application state.

Angular 1.x will "[dirty check](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle)" the `$scope` and make changes to the DOM. Anything on the `$scope` object can be watched, so you can observe the variable and trigger functions. This is why Angular searching & filtering can be done with almost no JS code at all. That being said, it's generally good practice to keep the '$scope' free of anything that isn't needed.

So as far as `getValue()` is concerned, is it being called on render or in a directive in your HTML? if the answer is "no", then it doesn't need to be declared as a property on the `$scope` object.

Since you're using `getValue()` in the directive template, it is being rendered in the UI and needs to be in Angular's `$scope`.

You can also just do:
   `directive.template = '{{ varx * 3 }}';`

docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that the code contains unnecessary nested calls. it can be:

```
  var getValue2 = function() {
    return scope.varx * 3;
  }

  scope.getValue = getValue2;
```

The second thing is that `getValue2` isn't reused and isn't needed, it can be:

```
  scope.getValue = function() {
    return scope.varx * 3;
  }
```

Since `getValue` is used in template, it should be exposed to scope as `scope.getValue`. Even if it wouldn't be used in template, it's a good practice to expose functions to scope for testability. So if there's a real need for `getValue2`, defining and calling it as `scope.getValue2` provides small overhead but improves testability.

Notice that the use of link function and direct access to scope object properties is an obsolete practice, while up-to-date approach involves `controllerAs` and `this`.